# How can I get the lastAccessTime on hive table?

Tags: pyspark, lastaccesstime

I am trying to get last access time on a hive table in pyspark function and have no success. I need this to determine which tables I can safely remove because they were not accessed in last 2 years.

I am able to get create date with this

```
f.regexp_extract('information', r'transient_lastDdlTime=(\d+)', 1).cast("bigint").alias('ddl_tm'),
```

I tried similar for AccessTime but had no success:

```
f.regexp_extract('information', r'transient_lastAccessTime=(\d+)', 1).cast("bigint").alias('lastAccessTime')
```